# DEPMOD File not found, how can i solve this?

Tags: java, android, linux, linux-kernel, rom

i'm new in Android ROM compiling and i'm doing this private build and happend this error after 1h30min, i could not found anything that can help me solve this error

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/onygan/peplus/out/target/product/ysl/obj/KERNEL_OBJ'
  INSTALL drivers/char/rdbg.ko
  INSTALL drivers/media/platform/msm/dvb/adapter/mpq-adapter.ko
  INSTALL drivers/media/platform/msm/dvb/demux/mpq-dmx-hw-plugin.ko
  INSTALL drivers/video/backlight/lcd.ko
  INSTALL fs/efivarfs/efivarfs.ko
  INSTALL net/bridge/br_netfilter.ko
  INSTALL net/ipv4/tcp_bic.ko
  INSTALL net/ipv4/tcp_htcp.ko
  INSTALL net/wireguard/wireguard.ko
  DEPMOD  4.9.262-perf+
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/onygan/peplus/out/target/product/ysl/obj/KERNEL_OBJ'
make: Leaving directory '/home/onygan/peplus/kernel/xiaomi/ysl'
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /home/onygan/peplus/out/target/product/ysl/obj/PACKAGING/depmod_vendor_intermediates/lib/modules/0.0: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /home/onygan/peplus/out/target/product/ysl/obj/PACKAGING/depmod_vendor_intermediates/lib/modules/0.0: No such file or directory
00:52:32 ninja failed with: exit status 1
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```